# I think I fried my IRF840 MOSFET, need help troubleshooting

Tags: mosfet

[image]

I have recently unsoldered an IRF840 MOSFET, and I tried using it on my breadboard. I connected everything correctly being: 1V-drain, button-gate, LED-source.

I tried running once, and it worked, but when I added a potentiometer, it stopped working. I am using an Arduino's pin as the power source if it might help answer, but all I need is an answer to what I did wrong and how to fix it (if possible.)

I am not sure if I am using NMOS but it was one the two MOSFETs on Tinkercad.

Comment: Put a schematic diagram of the circuit in the question, along with a photo of the circuit as built.

Comment: Why do you need a MOSFET to drive a plain old LED for? Isn't the AVR capable of driving at least some 6mA directly from the pin?

Answer (score 3):

If you connected it as in the drawing, then either the LED is dead or the MOSFET is dead.

The LED would probably die first.

Your circuit is something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Ju4m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Essentially, when the circuit goes on all the current the 5V source from the Arduino can deliver rushes through the LED.  Typical LEDs are rated for about 20 milliamperes.  The Arduino can deliver a few hundred milliamperes.  Too much current will kill an LED.

You need something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMDpt9.png)</sup>

R1 reduces the current to the LED to just a few milliamperes.

Comment: very helpful answer thx JRE

Comment: i am using a 1V from a Arduino pin, it can easily light a LED without breaking it

Comment: An Arduino pin can't put out 1V.  If you are using a GPIO, it is either 5V or 0V.  If you are using an "analog" output, keep in mind that the Arduino doesn't have analog outputs.  It has digital outputs that can be switched on and off (PWM.)

Comment: 1V is not enough to light up **any** visible light LED.  If the LED lights up, the voltage is much higher than 1V.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way to hook it up. Try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOEvNB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm guessing you tried putting the pot in series with the LED, right? When you do that, any voltage dropped across the pot reduces the gate/source voltage. The minimum gate voltage for an IRF840 can be as high as 4 volts,so you wound up with an LED which could not produce any more LED current. If you use a 6 volt supply, it would probably work.

The right way to do it is to connect the source to ground, so you get the full voltage at the gate.

The "right way" circuit isn't actually right - it NEEDS a resistor in series with the LED, or it will probably burn out the LED. I just drew it that way for comparison.

Comment: very helpful answer thx WhatRoughBeast

Comment: if I hooked it up wrong how did it work the first time? don't bother answering this i just share my thoughts

Comment: @ICODE Best guess is the LED burnt out from too much current. But I wasn't there when it happened, so it's just a guess. When a MOSFET dies, I think it's usually a short circuit, so the LED would be stuck on, not off.